# Can not open site in SharePoint Designer 2013 32 bit

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

When I tried to open the web application in SharePoint Designer 2013 32 bit, I got the below error message and it keeps asking me username and password. How can I open a web application in spd2013?

> The description for Event ID 0 from source MSOIDSVC.EXE cannot be
>   found.
>
> Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your
>   local computer or the installation is corrupted.
>
> You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> InitializeSvcAPI failed with hr = 0x80048883

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try to disable  `Microsoft Online Services Sign In Assistant` (MSOIDSVC.EXE) by running `Service.msc` > search about it> Stope or disable it from its properties.
- It's also recommended to use SharePoint Designer 2013 64 bit rather than 32 bit if your machine is 64 bit as mentioned [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office2010/2010/02/23/understanding-64-bit-office/)

Check also different solutions based on different situations for this error [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/microsoft-office-2013-has-stopped-working/0769edb6-1db1-44ff-8fae-a302214d70c2?page=4)